# Python not seeing an external object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, game-development

*** I believe the `lvl1[(x,y)] = getattr(__import__('mapTiles'), tile_name)(x, y)` is causing the problem, I changed it to a direct import with the same problem and the circular import here is... mapTiles imports world and inside the `load_tiles()` function, it imports mapTiles. I'm not sure how to restructure this to stop the circles, any ideas? ***
I'm making a text RPG game, I have all the tiles coded and able to be interacted with but when I go to run the game, it gives me the error below. I can't see a circular import anywhere so I don't understand what's going on. (Please tell me if you need any other code)

Error: (caused by load_tiles() which is called in play)

```
getattr(__import__('mapTiles'), tile_name)(x, y)
AttributeError: module 'mapTiles' has no attribute 'PlainsTile'
```

Only showing the base class and the one tile because there are about ten different ones
mapTiles.py

```
import actions, items, enemies, actions, world
class MapTile:
    def __init__(self,name, x, y, intro, description):
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y
        self.intro = intro

    def intro_text(self):
        return self.intro

    def terrain_interacts(self, terrain):
        # For elemental effects
        pass

    def randomize_interactions(self, tile):
        # Randomize enemy and loot spawns
        pass



    # Default actions
    def adjacent_moves(self):
        # Returns all move actions for adjacent tiles
        moves = []
        if world.tile_exists(self.x + 1, self.y):
            moves.append(actions.MoveEast())
        if world.tile_exists(self.x - 1, self.y):
            moves.append(actions.MoveWest())
        if world.tile_exists(self.x, self.y - 1):
            moves.append(actions.MoveNorth())
        if world.tile_exists(self.x, self.y + 1):
            moves.append(actions.MoveSouth())
        moves.append(actions.ViewInventory)
        return moves


    def available_actions(self):
        # Returns all available actions for the current tile
        moves = self.adjacent_moves()
        return moves


class PlainsTile(MapTile):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.name = "PlainsTile"
        self.intro = "You enter a plains"
        self.description = "A span of clear land, with the tall grass waving in the wind"
        super().__init__(
            name=self.name,
            intro=self.intro,
            description=self.description,
            x=self.x,
            y=self.y
        )
```

play.py

```
#play.py
import character, world

def play_game(player):
    world.load_tiles()
    print("Called")
    #These lines load the starting room and display the text
    tile = world.tile_exists(x=player.location_x, y=player.location_y)
    if tile != None:
        print(tile)
    while player.is_alive() and not player.victory:
        tile = world.tile_exists(player.location_x, player.location_y)
        # Check again since the room could have changed the player's state
        if player.is_alive() and not player.victory:
            print("Choose an action:\n")
            last[0] = player.location_x
            last[1] = player.location_y
            if tile != None:
                available_actions = tile.available_actions()
                if tile.name == 'BossTile' and player.victory:
                    tile.modify_character(player)
                for action in available_actions:
                    print(available_actions.name)
                for action in available_actions:

                    action_input = input("Choose an action ya prick: ")
                    if action_input == "quit":
                        quit()
                    if action_input == action.keyword:
                        player.do_action(action, **action.kwargs)
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Please choose one of the listed actions")
            else:
                print("You cannot go that way")
```

world.py

```
# No imports
lvl1 = {}

def load_tiles():
    """Parses a file that describes the world space into the _world object"""
    with open('m1.txt', 'r') as f:
        rows = f.readlines()
    x_max = len(rows[0].split('\t')) # Assumes all rows contain the same number of tabs
    for y in range(len(rows)):
        cols = rows[y].split('\t')
        for x in range(x_max):
            tile_name = cols[x].replace('\n', '') # Windows users may need to replace '\r\n'
            if tile_name == 'StartingRoom':
                global starting_position
                starting_position = (x, y)
            if tile_name == '':
                lvl1[(x, y)] = None
            else:
                getattr(__import__('mapTiles'), tile_name)(x, y)
def tile_exists(x,y):
    return lvl1.get((x,y))
```

imports from all other files

```
#items.py
#No imports

#actions.py
from play import player
import items
#enemies.py
import random

#character.py
import world, items, random
```

Comment: There's no reason to be importing dynamically. Just import `mapTiles` directly, then you can do `getattr(mapTiles, tile_name)(x, y)`.

Comment: Could this be happening because of the `getattr(__import__('mapTiles'), tile_name)(x,y)` ?  Since mapTiles imports from world, would this cause a circular import? How should I restructure this?

Comment: Daniel, I just tried it and it's still saying `AttributeError: module 'mapTiles' has no attribute 'PlainsTile'`

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it, the error was the import from getattr. I merged the two files, added a try/except to catch index errors and added a bunch of conditionals that instantiate the tile name at whatever coordinates.

Comment: You are getting downvoted because your question does not provide a [mcve]. Just dumping all your code and asking for people to fix it is not how you should use stack overflow, this is not a debugging service. check out [ask] and [help]. For the record, I did not downvote.

Comment: Thank you for actually telling me what I'm doing wrong. I apologize for not giving reproducible example. I didn't want to just dump like 6 files worth of code in here, I figured with the play_game and load_tiles functions would provide the required information since they're the ones causing problems. Plus since the load_tiles() funciton reads from a txt file, I didn't think I could put that in. as well. Still not sure how to go about asking about something like this since it's so large. Again, thank you for actually being helpful.